# Can we have a way to remove all our comments under a post?

Tags: feature-request, comments

Often a quite long discussion is needed in the comments section in order to clarify a post or reach some agreement. And the suggestion to "move the discussion to chat" doesn't make sense for new users. It would be very useful in such situations to be able to easily remove all my comments under a particular post after the discussion has finished.

I'm not referring to flame wars or other off-topic, nonsense discussions. Here is an example:

I've recently answered a question from a new user, and we needed quite a while to clarify my answer. It was because I incorrectly assumed that the user knows how *references* work, and in fact it was the only bit they were missing. The discussion was thus essential and impossible to carry out in a chat room.

After discussing this notion we've reached an understanding, and I suggested that we should now remove our comments. As a side note: it was this rare moment when a completely new user is actually a reasonable person, who considers all the suggestions and gladly accepts explanations on "how do things work here". So, after a few moments I've noticed all the user's comments deleted and started to delete my own.

And I thought to myself that it would be very convenient to do this with fewer mouse clicks, for example (the comment thread in this picture is not the one from the example described above):

[image]

After clicking the new button:

[image]

Of course the actual position of the button, it's shape and title may vary, this is just a simple example.

Pros:

- Easy way to tidy up (obviously)
- Less work for moderators (less "other" flags with "please tidy up the comments")
- The mere existence of such button will encourage users to delete their comments
- Shouldn't be hard to implement, especially when a similar feature exists for moderators (just a blind guess of course, but surely less than [6 to 8 Weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/231717))
- [Freehand circles!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/231717)

Cons:

- Needs to be implemented :V

---

Advanced version:

Of course, it would be super cool to have a dialog box with checkboxes allowing user to choose comments to delete, in case when, for example, one of them would still be relevant and the user would want to delete all but this one.

---

Another "advanced" version inspired by [The Minion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3615471/the-minion)'s [comment below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269613/can-we-have-a-way-to-remove-all-our-comments-under-a-post#comment84293_269613): if we don't want to have lots of comments hanging without a context, the feature could work as follows:

- User A clicks "nuke comments" button.
- This is visible for other participants (perhaps even via a notification). E.g. "User A suggests clearing the comments".
- Users B, C, etc... also click "nuke comments"
- Because of the aggrement, all comments are being deleted. The Universe is a bit more clean.

For many typical scenarios this would work fine and effectively.

Comment: This would be cool, but I understand that [the infuriating 5 second waiting period between deleting comments was recently tweaked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238331/153008), so this probably isn't as big of a problem now as it used to be.

Comment: Because it doesn't need to be implemented (IMO), I almost down voted despite liking your suggestion (being a very verbose commentator myself :-P), but decided not to as you might not have known about the update for next build that Cody mentions above. Unless you read here way too much (like Cody Gray, who may be imprisoned in some hidden StackExchange cubical, LOL), you'd probably not come across this stuff.

Comment: @CodyGray, @HowardPautz Yes, that's true that removing the *5 seconds madness* helps a lot, but still `O(1)` clicks are better than `O(n)` clicks :-)

Comment: While it may not be so necessary as it used to be, I think it'd be a good UI addition and would fit in with the recent-ish changes to showing comments.

Comment: The problem I see is that if you have a "discussion" with one or two other users and you delete all of your comments all the other comments get torn out of context. Thats why in my opinion you shouldn't be able to delete comments at all but rather have the chance to say hide them. And only if people explicitly click on your hided comment it gets visible.

Comment: Less is more. We don't need a button for that.

Comment: @TheMinion It still happens, when people do delete their comments manually. Unless, we really want to recommend the approach of involing a moderator each time

Comment: @GeorgeBailey More unnecessary work for moderators that is? :)

Comment: @TheMinion I've added another possible version of this feature that addresses your concern.

Comment: Nah.

Especially now that that cooldown is being removed, I really don't see the benefit of adding a "Nuke all my comments" button.

Comment: id add a button to delete all comments to own answer/question, especially the pedantic ones